# String manipulation

Tags: code-golf, string

**The challenge is to manipulate strings using basic Vim-like commands**

**Input:**

- A string of text to be transformed. The input alphabet is [a-z].
- A string of legal commands

**Output:**

- The transformed string

---

There are a few ideas you should understand:

The cursor is represented as a location between 2 characters. `|` will be used to represent the cursor(s) in this explanation.

- `|foobar` - The cursor at beginning of string
- `foo|bar` - Cursor in the middle of the string
- `foobar|` - Cursor at the end of the string

A selection is a a group of characters between 2 cursors.

- `|foobar|` - The selection is `foobar`
- `|foo|bar` - The selection is `foo`
- `foo|bar|` - the selection is `bar`
- `|foobar`  - The selection is the empy string (both cursors at same location)

A selection is formed from the previous cursor position and the result of the current command.

Using the command `>` on `|foo` would make the selection `|f|oo`.

Commands can be described as functions. `C<selection>` is a command that has a selection parameter. The next command provides the selection.

- `D>` deletes the character to the right of the cursor. `f|oo` `->` `f|o`
- `DNa` deletes from the cursor to the next `a` character `f|oobar` `->` `f|ar`
- Etc.

As you can see, commands "associate to the right"

- `DNa` is parsed as `(D(Na))`
- `DDNa` is parsed as `(D(D(Na)))`
- Etc.

The insert mode command `I` extends until the next command.

- `DIbar>` is parsed as `(D(Ibar))(>)`.

**These are the commands:**

- `>` - Move cursor right. `>` on `foo|bar` `->` `foob|ar`
- `<` - Move cursor left. `<` on `foo|bar` `->` `fo|obar`
- `B` - Move cursor to the beginning of the string
- `E` - Move cursor to the end of the string
- `N<char>` - Move cursor to place before next `<char>`. `Na` on `|foobar` `->` `foob|ar`
- `P<char>` - Move cursor to place after previous `<char>`.  `Po` on `foobar|` `->` `foo|bar`
- `I<string>` - Enter/exit insert mode. Characters in `<string>` are inserted at the current cursor position. `<string>` extends until the next command.
  The cursor is moved to end of insertion `<string>`. `Iquz` on `foo|bar` `->` `fooquz|bar`
- `D<selection>` - delete characters in `<selection>`. `f|ooba|r` `->` `f|r`. The output selection from this command is the empty string.

**Notes:**

- The cursor cannot move out of bounds. `B<<<` is the same as `B`. `Nx` is the same as `E` if no `x` can be found.
- The cursor location always starts at the beginning of the string
- The cursor should not be outputted
- Commands are always uppercase, characters are lowercase.

**Restrictions:**

- No text editor scripts like Vimscript

**Winning criteria:**

- It's code golf. Lowest character count wins.

---

**Examples:**

Input:

- `foobar`
- `>>><<>If`

Output:

- `fofobar`

---

Input:

- `foobar`
- `>>>DNEDPf`

Output:

- `f`

---

Input:

- `foobar`
- `>>>DDDDIbazD<Iquz>DPfDII`

Output:

- `far`

Comment: "`<string>` extends until the next command."

But how do we know that it's a command rather than part of the string?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Commands are uppercase, characters are lower.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this question might be a bit too complicated for a code-golf tag.

Comment: The first example is like teaching a 4th grader how to multiply; the second example is like trying to teach that 4th grader algebra, and the third example is like trying to teach that 4th grader calculus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Haskell, 371 characters

```
z l b n i=p where
 p(a:c@ ~(q:u))|Just x<-a`lookup`zip"<>BEDNP"[l#c,m l#c,b#c,m b#c,z(d$k id)(\k _->k"")h(k f)c,m(n q)#u,n q#u]=x
 p('I':q:c)|q>'`'=i q c;p(_:c)=f c;p""=(++).r
d f k(q:x)=k x.f q;d f k""=k"";k&x=k"".(r x++);h q=(.snd.s q);n q k=(\(a,b)->k b.(r a++)).s q
x%c=f c""x;f=z(d(:))(&)n$ \q c->f('I':c).(q:);m f=flip.f.flip;k=const;r=reverse;(#)=(.f);s=span.(/=)
```

This defines a function `%` which returns the result of applying the string of commands to the original string.

**Example usage:**

```
> "foobar" % ">>>DNEDPf"
"f"
> "foobar" % ">>>DDDDIbazD<Iquz>DPfDII"
"far"
```